# AWS Lambda not waiting for Promise.all() from DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, aws-lambda

I'm fairly new to Promises on NodeJS and am trying to write some backend code in AWS Lambda to query a DynamoDB Table which contains devices.

The code is the following:

```
            var geohash = require('ngeohash');
            var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
            var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

            exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

                if(event.params.querystring.minLat && event.params.querystring.minLon
                    && event.params.querystring.maxLat && event.params.querystring.maxLon ){

                        var bboxes = geohash.bboxes(event.params.querystring.minLat, event.params.querystring.minLon, event.params.querystring.maxLat, event.params.querystring.maxLon, 6);

                        var params = {
                            "TableName": "Devices",
                            "IndexName": "GeoIndex",
                            "KeyConditionExpression": "GeohashPrefix = :bbox",
                            "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
                                ":bbox": ""
                            },
                        };

                        var devices = [];
                        var promises = [];

                        for (var num in bboxes) {
                            params.ExpressionAttributeValues[":bbox"] = bboxes[num];
                            promises = promises.concat(documentClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Query succeeded.");
                                    devices = devices.concat(data.Items);
                                    console.log(devices);
                                }
                            }).promise())
                        }
                        Promise.all(promises).then(callback(null, devices));
                    }

                }
```

What happens here is that Promise.all() does not actually wait for all promises but returns immediately.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `then()`, not the result of a function.

This:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(callback(null, devices));
```

should be more like this:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(() => callback(null, devices));
```

In the first case `callback` is called immediately when the promise is defined.